# prevent duplicates items listview form listbox asp.net mvc3

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, listbox

I have an `IEnumerable` list to which I want to prevent the addition of a duplicate item (an item already existing in the list) from my listbox. I have found that I must use LINQ but since I am new with ASP.NET. I didn't know how to compare my list item  with the listbox items while adding a new one to my list:

This is how my list is displayed ::

```
   public ActionResult Liste()
   {
     try
     {
        List<RubriquepointageVM> lstVM = ServiceApplicatif.GetListe()
                                                          .OrderBy(x => x.Rubrique_PointageId)
                                                          .ToList();

        //  Drop Down List des listRubrique

        IEnumerable<RubriqueVM> listRubrique = RefDataManager.GetRefData<RubriqueVM>() as IEnumerable<RubriqueVM>;
        if (listRubrique.Any())
        {
            ViewBag.idrub = listRubrique.First().RubriqueId;
        }

        ViewData["CodeRubrique"] = new SelectList(listRubrique, "RubriqueId", "CODELIBELLE");

        return View(lstVM);
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LoggerRubriquepointage.Error(string.Format("Exception : {0}", ex.Message.ToString()));
        throw new Exception("Erreur lors du chargement.");
    }
}
```

What I want to know is how to use LINQ to prevent the addition of an existing item in my Rubriqueintermediarelist from my listbox.

my Save() methode :

```
public JsonResult Save([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest dsRequest, RubriquepointageVM vm)
    {
        try
        {
            IEnumerable<RubriqueVM> listRubrique = RefDataManager.GetRefData<RubriqueVM>() as IEnumerable<RubriqueVM>;
            ViewData["CodeRubrique"] = new SelectList(RefDataManager.GetRefData<RubriqueVM>(), "RubriqueId", "CODELIBELLE", 976);

            List<RubriquepointageVM> lstRubriqueinter = ServiceApplicatif.GetListe();

            **//Iwant my test to be her before adding an item**

           RubriquepointageVM rub = ServiceApplicatif.Save(vm); 


        DataCache dataCache = new DataCache(CurrentSecurityContext.TenantID);
            dataCache.DropDataCache<RubriquepointageVM>();

            return Json(new[] { lstVMrub }.ToDataSourceResult(dsRequest, ModelState));

        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LoggerRubriquepointage.Error(string.Format("Exception : {0}", ex.Message.ToString()));
            throw new Exception("Erreur lors de l'enregistrement.");


        }
```

Comment: Could you possibly add some more comments to your code to explain step by step what you want to do. It doesn't seem patently obvious - to me at least.

Comment: @Tomás what i want to do exactly is: in my Save() methode :when adding a new item from my combobox:ViewData["CodeRubrique"]: to chek first if this item elready existed in my list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comments, I cannot see exactly what you are trying to do but from what I gather I would try something like:

```
    if(! lstRubriqueinter.Any(x => x.RubriqueId == vm.RubriqueId))
    {
           RubriquepointageVM rub = ServiceApplicatif.Save(vm); 
        // you may need to add this rub to the list at this point. You will  have a better idea.
    }
```

I haven't tested this code because I don't have much to go on really from your question.

Comment: i have edited my article to clear my question,even that please explain for me what you have coded for me

Comment: ok, I have edited the answer to apply more corretly to your situation. As far as I understand it you want to add your new Rubrique item to the lstRubriqueinter list only if it is not there. My code does that. It says "if there aren't any Rubriques 'x' with the same RubriqueId as the vm that you are saving then go ahead and save.

Comment: yes it works for me just i change the **listRubrique** by **lstRubriqueinter** because it is the listview to add in :  but it just didn't allow to add the same item how could i add an error message must i use a **modelstate Validation**?

Comment: Hi smarttech. I'm sorry. The validation question is a little beyond me as it has been a long time since I worked in MVC and I can't make any meaningful suggestion here. I'd have to go Googling - which I am sure you are well capable of doing yourself ;-) If I think of how I'll be back with an answer!

Comment: Hi Tomás,thanks a lot for your help ,I'm very grateful for your help, it's ok i found what i need by Googling:i just add the message validation :  
                        ** ModelState.AddModelError("Rubrique", "erreur de doublons");**